# disable python greeting/version info

Tags: python, console

When I start a python interactive session from the command line I am greeted by :

```
 Python 3.9.6 (default, Jun 30 2021, 10:22:16) 
 [GCC 11.1.0] on linux
 Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
```

Is there a way of disabling that message so that I go immediately to the `>>>` prompt?

Comment: `-q` is the way to go, as seen in the answer from Eladtopaz. If you are looking for more options, check out the documentation: https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, there is a way to do so.
Type in the cmd:

```
python -q
```

instead of

```
python
```

and this should do the trick.